# Location of Whatsapp Web sessions

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, geolocation

From a few sources (see below for examples), I learned about the possibility of locating the computers connected via Whatsapp Web and/or desktop apps, by simply tapping the relevant item in the list of connected computers (available from ... > Whatsapp Web); supposedly, doing so should automatically show you the computer's location on Google Maps.
However, that does not seem to work on my phone; whenever I try, I am just asked whether I want to disconnect from that computer. Moreover, all those pages I found seem to be more than one year old.

Do you know whether such a feature exists, and

- if so, how to use it (i.e., why doesn't it work on my phone)?
- if not, did it exist once and why was it discontinued?

Here are some sources (admittedly not very authoritative ones, and I could not find much better, but I cannot see the point in inventing and spreading such a lie):

- a Youtube [video](https://youtu.be/9dIwLdW3Jwc?t=2m44s)
- a tech [webpage in Italian](https://www.wordsmart.it/vedere-chi-ti-spia-su-whatsapp/)

Comment: Can you post links as to where you found that such a thing exists?

Comment: The thing is, I cannot find any _good_ sources (and that's part of the reason why I'm asking here). Anyway, I added a couple of examples at the end of the question. The video looks genuine…

Comment: Searching all over, i couldn't find anything on this either. Very possible the video is fake. Wouldn't be the first fake video on YouTube. Also possible that WhatsApp tried this in a beta version but didn't implement it. I guess let's see if anyone has an answer. Up-Voting as a good question.